# How can I select every first data of time in every-dates? on crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to select all first data of time in every dates with the type of f1.
How can I do that on Crystal report?
Do I need to create an SQL Expression? Or any suggestions?

```
ID no.  Employee Name  Dates      Time    Type
389     Escano,CL.    16-Aug-20   7:45am   F1 
389     Escano,CL.    16-Aug-20   7:47am   F1 
389     Escano,CL.    17-Aug-20   7:45am   F1 
389     Escano,CL.    17-Aug-20   7:47am   F1 
389     Escano,CL.    18-Aug-20   7:47am   F1 
389     Escano,CL.    18-Aug-20   7:49am   F1
```

Answer (score 0):

group by `idno` and `dates` then `Top N` against `time`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT     id, name, date, time, type FROM dbo.test AS t1 
WHERE (time IN(SELECT     TOP (1) time FROM dbo.test AS t 
WHERE (date = t1.date) ORDER BY time))
```

**Result**

```
ID no.  Employee Name  Dates      Time     Type
389     Escano,CL.    2020-08-16  07:45:00  F1
389     Escano,CL.    2020-08-17  07:45:00  F1
389     Escano,CL.    2020-08-18  07:47:00  F1
```